# how to compile under android the appRTCmobile demo?

Tags: webrtc

How to compile under android the `appRTCmobile` demo (located in example\androidapp) ? Also Where to find some already compiled apk of this demo ?

Answer (score 0):

when you compile the android framework for webrtc, following those steps:
https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

the application should be compiled along.

Answer (score 0):

Follow official tutorial how to build [WebRTC build for android](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/androidapp/README).

But there is more simplest and fastest way, don't compile WebRTC sdk and just use one of the already pre-buil versions of [WebRTC sdk](https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc) for demo application.

Just create new project, based on [official Demo sources](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/androidapp) and add WebRtc SDK as dependency in application gradle file.

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25331'
```